# CSS: Things get moved around in scaled-up print preview in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, printing

Page: (http://progrock.rocks/teaching_materials/loops.html).

It's everything (CSS, JavaScript and HTML) in one file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2016 Alf P. Steinbach. Boost 1.0 license. -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lapper for «loops» gruppeøvelse i praktisk regning</title>
        <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
        <style>
            * { font: 10pt sans-serif; }
            body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: white; }
            h1
            {
                padding-left: 14px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0.5em; padding-right: 0;
                margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;
                background-color: lightGray;
                font-size: xx-large; font-style: italic; color: #A0B0B0;
            }
            div#content
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;
                position: absolute; width: 100%;
            }
            div#input-area
            {
                left: 0; right: -0;
                padding-left: 14px; padding-right: 14px;
                padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;
                margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;
                background-color: #F0F0F0;
            }
            div#notes-container
            {
                left: 0; right: -0;
                padding-left: 14px; padding-right: 14px;
                padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;
                margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;
                /*display: none;*/
            }
            input.Number-input
            {
                width: 5em;
            }
            .Access-key
            {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            div.Note
            {
                margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 12px;
                margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 0px;

                padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em;
                padding-top: 1em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;

                background-color: #FFFFB0;
                width: 15em;
                overflow: hidden;

                border-radius: 1em;
                border: 1px gray solid;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            div.Note-figure
            {
                float: right; font-size: 4em; color: #D0E0E0;
                padding: 0px; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top;
                transform: rotate(-7deg);
                border-radius: 0.5em;
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function item( id )
            {
                return document.getElementById( id );
            }

            function generate()
            {
                const n_notes = 11;
                const operand = parseInt( item( "fixed-operand" ).value );
                const operation = item( "operation" ).value;    // +, *
                const start_number = (operation == "+"? 0 : 1);

                console.log( "Generate" )
                var container = item( "notes-container" );
                var collection = item( "notes-collection" );
                if( collection !== null )
                {
                    collection.remove();
                    collection = null;
                }
                var message = document.createTextNode("Genererer…");
                container.appendChild( message );

                collection = document.createElement( "div" );
                collection.id = "notes-collection";

                var template = item( "note-template" )
                console.log( "template = " + template )
                var current = start_number;
                for( let i = 0; i < n_notes; ++i )
                {
                    let note = template.cloneNode( true );
                    note.style.display = "inline-block";
                    let note_has = note.querySelector( "#note-has" );
                    note_has.innerHTML = "Jeg har " + current.toString() + ".";
                    let note_seeking = note.querySelector( "#note-seeking" );
                    let display_op = (operation == "+"? " + " : "∙");
                    note_seeking.innerHTML = "Hvem har " + current + display_op + operand + "?";
                    if( i == n_notes - 1 ) { note_seeking.innerHTML = "Siste tall!"; }
                    let figure = note.querySelector( "#figure" );
                    switch( operation )
                    {
                        case "+": figure.innerHTML = i + "∙" + operand; break;
                        case "*": figure.innerHTML = operand + "↑" + i; break;
                    }

                    collection.appendChild( note );
                    switch( operation )
                    {
                        case "+": current += operand; break;
                        case "*": current *= operand; break;
                    }
                }
                message.remove();
                container.appendChild( collection );
            }

            function explanation_of( op )
            {
                switch( op )
                {
                    case "+":   return "dette gir en gangetabell";
                    case "-":   return "dette gir en baklengs gangetabell";
                    case "*":   return "dette gir en potenstabell";
                    case "/":   return "dette gir en baklengs potenstabell";
                }
            }

            function update_explanation()
            {
                item( "operation-explanation" ).innerHTML =
                    "(" + explanation_of( item( "operation" ).value ) + ").";
            }

            function on_command_generate()
            {
                generate();
            }

            function on_operation_changed()
            {
                update_explanation();
            }

            function on_document_loaded()
            {
                item( "title-header" ).innerHTML = document.title;
                item( "operation" ).value = "+";
                update_explanation();
                generate();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="on_document_loaded()">
        <h1 id="title-header">asdasd</h1>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="input-area">
                <select id="operation" onchange="on_operation_changed();">
                    <option value="+">+ (addisjon)</option>
                    <option value="*">* (multiplikasjon)</option>
                </select>
                med fast operand
                <input id="fixed-operand" type="number"
                    class="Number-input"
                    alt="Det faste tallet i utregningene"
                    value="2"
                    min="1"
                    max="10"
                    >
                <span id="operation-explanation"></span>
                <button onclick="on_command_generate();" accesskey="g">
                    <span class="Access-key">G</span>enerér
                </button>
            </div> <!-- input-area -->
            <div id="notes-container">
                <div id="note-template" class="Note" style="display:none">
                    <div id="figure" class="Note-figure">
                        5∙7
                    </div>
                    <div style="position: absolute">
                        <span id="note-has">Jeg har 35</span>
                        <br/>
                        &nbsp;<br/>
                        <span id="note-seeking">Hvem har 35 + 7?</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="notes-collection">
                </div>  <!-- notes-collection -->
            <div> <!-- notes-container -->
        </div> <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem: while print preview in 100% works nicely,

[image]

when I scale up the print preview, things after or around the page break get moved around it and the result is just ugly and unusable for the purpose:

[image]

I've tried, on another machine, a CSS property that should prevent page break within a `div.Note-figure`, but that didn't work. Sorry I don't have it here. I've also tried googling problems with Firefox print preview, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what caused the printing preview problem in Firefox, but I fixed it by giving each yellow note *positioning*, namely `position: relative;`, and giving the text `div` inside the note `position: absolute`.

I also gave the text-`div` a `z-index: 1` so it can float over the large gray text when the space gets too crammed.

The main problem with this kind of solution is that, without an understanding of the causes of the problem, the solution is pretty arbitrary and hence not very reproducible. So I would appreciate it if someone could explain what was going on and exactly why this approach works. Assuming that it's not a Firefox bug?

```
div.Note
{
    margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 8px; margin-left: 0px;

    padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em;
    padding-top: 1em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;

    background-color: #FFFFB0;
    width: 15em;
    overflow: hidden;

    border-radius: 1em;
    border: 1px gray solid;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative;
}
div.Note-text
{
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute; z-index: 1;
}
div.Note-figure
{
    float: right; font-size: 4em; color: #D0E0E0;
    padding: 0px; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top;
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
}
```